# How to add .fadeIn effect in jquery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to add a .fadeIn effect to a script instead of .animate, but it doesn't work. Basically, I try to make fading in elements when you scroll to them. This is the script and HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each(function(i) {

      var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
      var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

      /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
      if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {

        $(this).animate({
          'opacity': '1'
        }, 1500);

      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.hideme {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hideme">
  <p>This is some text.</p>
</div>
<div class="hideme">
  <p>This is some text.</p>
</div>
<div class="hideme">
  <p>This is some text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: And you decided to post the working code, not the non-working code ?

Comment: As your element are visible, they just have no opacity, you don't want to use `fadeIn`, you actually want to use `animate` or even jQuery's `fadeTo`.

Comment: And  how to add the fadeIn then. Could you please show an example please? I am concerned because I think fadeIn looks better than animate, am I right?

Comment: Makes no difference, `fadeIn` is just a convience method that uses `animate` internally

Comment: Ok. Thx for help! I didnt know that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  /* Check the location of each desired element */
  $('.hideme').each(function(i) {
   var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
   var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
   /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
   if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
    $(this).fadeIn(400, function(){
     $(this).css('opacity', 1)
    });
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```css
.hideme {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hideme">
  <p>This is some text.</p>
</div>
<div class="hideme">
  <p>This is some text.</p>
</div>
<div class="hideme">
  <p>This is some text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.